# Google translate dropdown not working in IE7 and IE9

Tags: javascript, google-translate

Here is the code I am using to add the drop down in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
             pageLanguage: 'en',
             //includedLanguages: 'zh-CN,zh-TW,es'
        }, 'google_translate_element');
     }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Yes it does work in IE8 firefox and chrome. In IE7 it's displaying blank instead of dropdown. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the div to display the dropdown?  Try this:

```
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: I have missed to copy that div in the question, but I do have the div like this <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

Comment: Try your code in a blank page to verify that it works correctly first.  Do you have a URL you can send?